# My Jquery tools Ajax modal login is not working in IE 7 and 8

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am working on modal login/registration forms. I'm not good with Javascript, but have hacked my way to some working Jquery for my Ajax call, and all is working nicely in Chrome 14.0.835.159 beta-m and in Firefox 5 and 6.0.2 and Opera 11.51. I used Firebug to see the JSON returning correctly and updating the error messages.

In FF/Opera/Chrome if I leave the username and login blank and I click the login button on the modal window, the returns count up the failed logins and display the return.I used firebuggerhttp://www.firebugger.com/ to look at what was going on in On IE 7 and 8.

If you leave the form fields blank, it seems the form is somehow "cached" and the call doesnt go through. None of the returns act on my login javascript to update the loginMsg div. If you change the input each time, "a", "as", "asd", the return counts up the failed logins as intended but still no update on my div

Very odd :-(

The test page is at [camarillon.com/testpage.cfm](http://camarillon.com/testpage.cfm)

```
<!DOCType html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>testpage - test ajax login</title>
    <!-- include the Tools --> 
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 

<!--- add styles --->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loginbox.css" /> 
<!--- <noscript>This is what you see without javascript</noscript> --->

    <CFSET structDelete(session, 'form')>
    <cfset session.form.validate_require="username|'Username' is required.;password|'Password' is required.;confirmpassword|'Confirm password' is a required field.;">
    <cfset session.form.validate_minlength="username|'Username' must be at least 3 characters long.;password|'Password' must be at least 7 characters long.">
    <cfset session.form.validate_maxlength="username|'Username' must be less than 6 characters long.">
    <cfset session.form.validate_alphanumeric="username|'Username' must be alphanumeric.">
    <cfset session.form.validate_password="confirmpassword|password|'Password' and 'Confirm Password' must both match.">

</head>

<body>

<cfparam name="session.auth.loggedIn" default="false">

    <div id="loginMenu">
    <cfif session.auth.loggedIn>
        <a href="logout.cfm">Log out</a>
    <cfelse>
        <button class="modalInput" rel="#login">Login</button>
        <button class="modalInput" rel="#register">Register</button>
    </cfif>
    </div> 


<!-- user input dialog -->
<cfif isDefined("session.auth.failedLogins")>
    <cfset loginMsg=#session.auth.failedLogins# & " failed logins">
<cfelse>
    <cfset loginMsg="Please log in">
</cfif>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({
    // some mask tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
    mask: {
        color: '#ccc',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    closeOnClick: false,
    onClose: function () {
        $('.error').hide();
    }
});

$("#toomanylogins").overlay({
mask: {
        color: '#ccc', 
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9
    },
    closeOnClick: false,
    load: false
});

$("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    // submit with AJAX
    $.getJSON("cfcs/security.cfc?method=processLogin&ajax=1&returnformat=JSON&queryformat=column&" + form.serialize(), function(json) {
        // everything is ok. (server returned true)
        if (json === true)  {
            // close the overlay
            triggers.eq(0).overlay().close();
            $("#loginMenu").html("<a href='logout.cfm'>Log out</a>");
            // server-side validation failed. use invalidate() to show errors
        } else if (json === "More than five") {
            var tempString
            tempString = "<h2>Too many failed logins </h2>"
            $("#loginMsg").html(tempString);
            triggers.eq(0).overlay().close();
            $("#toomanylogins").overlay().load();
        } else {
            var tempString
            tempString = "<h2>" + json + " failed logins</h2>"
            $("#loginMsg").html(tempString);
        }
    });
    // prevent default form submission logic
    e.preventDefault();
}); 


// initialize validator and add a custom form submission logic
$("#signupForm").validator().submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    // client-side validation OK.
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // submit with AJAX
        $.getJSON("cfcs/security.cfc?method=processSignup&returnformat=JSON&queryformat=column&" + form.serialize(), function(json) {
            // everything is ok. (server returned true)
            if (json === true)  {
                // close the overlay
                triggers.eq(1).overlay().close();
                $("#loginMenu").html("<a href='logout.cfm'>Log out</a>");
            // server-side validation failed. use invalidate() to show errors
            } else {
                form.data("validator").invalidate(json);
            }
        });
        // prevent default form submission logic
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$.tools.validator.fn("[minlength]", function(input, value) {
    var min = input.attr("minlength");
    return value.length >= min ? true : {     
        en: "Please provide at least " +min+ " character" + (min > 1 ? "s" : ""),
    };
});

$.tools.validator.fn("[data-equals]", "Value not equal with the $1 field", function(input) {
    var name = input.attr("data-equals"),
         field = this.getInputs().filter("[name=" + name + "]"); 
    return input.val() == field.val() ? true : [name]; 
});

});
</script> 

<!-- yes/no dialog -->
<div class="modal" id="toomanylogins">
    <h2>Having problems logging in?</h2>
    <p>
    If you have forgotten your password you can request a reset.
    </p>

    <!-- yes/no buttons -->
    <p>
        <button class="close"> Cancel </button>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="login"> 
    <!-- login form --> 
    <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off"  method="get" action="">
    <div id="loginMsg"><h2><cfoutput>#loginMsg#</cfoutput></h2></div>
    <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username..." title="Must be at least 8 characters." <!--- required="required"  --->></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password..." title="Try to make it hard to guess" <!--- required="required" --->></p>
    <p>
    <button type="submit"> Login </button> 
    <button type="button" class="close"> Cancel </button>
    </p>
    </form>
</div> 

<div  class="modal" id="register">
<!-- signup form-->
    <form id="signupForm"  autocomplete="off" method="get" action=""  novalidate="novalidate">





    <fieldset>
<p>
    <label>firstname *</label>
    <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname..." required="required"/></p>
    <p>
    <label>lastname *</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname..." required="required"/></p>
    <p>
    <label>email *</label>
    <input  type="email" name="email" placeholder="email..." required="required"/></p>
    <p>
    <label>username *</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username..."  required="required"/>     
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>password *<br>
    <input type="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="password..." /></label>     
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>confirm password *<br>
    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" data-equals="password"  placeholder="password..."  required="required"/></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        <button type="button" class="close"> Cancel </button>
    </p>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Back end is in Coldfusion, but I don't think thats relevant, the JSON returns work just fine in FF etc

Any pointers about what I presume is some bug in my Javascript appreciated, my JQuery kung foo is not strong :-(

Logans solution below is correct ... I also had a trailing comma in here which was wrong only bugging out in IE 5-7

```
$.tools.validator.fn("[minlength]", function(input, value) {
    var min = input.attr("minlength");
    return value.length >= min ? true : {     
        en: "Please provide at least " +min+ " character" + (min > 1 ? "s" : ""),
    };
});
```

should have been

```
$.tools.validator.fn("[minlength]", function(input, value) {
    var min = input.attr("minlength");
    return value.length >= min ? true : {     
        en: "Please provide at least " +min+ " character" + (min > 1 ? "s" : "")
    };
});
```

Comment: Glad it is working. Trailing commas are always annoying. I'd recommend learning to use the Firebug Firefox extension and IE8's developer tools. The make it very easy to find syntax errors and broken code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using $.getJSON, you can use $.ajax and set the cache option to false. I think that sound fix the issue.

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);


    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "cfcs/security.cfc?method=processLogin&ajax=1&returnformat=JSON&queryformat=column&" + form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(json) {
            // everything is ok. (server returned true)
            if (json === true)  {
                // close the overlay
                triggers.eq(0).overlay().close();
                $("#loginMenu").html("<a href='logout.cfm'>Log out</a>");
                // server-side validation failed. use invalidate() to show errors
            } else if (json === "More than five") {
                var tempString
                tempString = "<h2>Too many failed logins </h2>"
                $("#loginMsg").html(tempString);
                triggers.eq(0).overlay().close();
                $("#toomanylogins").overlay().load();
            } else {
                var tempString
                tempString = "<h2>" + json + " failed logins</h2>"
                $("#loginMsg").html(tempString);
            }
        }
    });

    // prevent default form submission logic
    e.preventDefault();
}); 


// initialize validator and add a custom form submission logic
$("#signupForm").validator().submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    // client-side validation OK.
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // submit with AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "cfcs/security.cfc?method=processSignup&returnformat=JSON&queryformat=column&" + form.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(json) {
                // everything is ok. (server returned true)
                if (json === true)  {
                    // close the overlay
                    triggers.eq(1).overlay().close();
                    $("#loginMenu").html("<a href='logout.cfm'>Log out</a>");
                // server-side validation failed. use invalidate() to show errors
                } else {
                    form.data("validator").invalidate(json);
                }
            }
        });
        // prevent default form submission logic
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: @scr4ve has got it. You're success callback isn't tabbed properly, so it is harder to see, but you have no } closing your success callback.

Comment: Confused, now, I was just updating my post to say I had it working. I'm not seeing a bug on my testpage this end (in IE 8 or FF). If you are still seeing a bug can you point it out even more simply for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   cache: false
 });
```

at the beginning of document ready?
Really looks like a problem with the jQuery Cache. If this helps, it certainly is.